# Error 1064 on create trigger mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064, mariadb-10.6

I try to do tregger BEFORE UPDATE but keep getting an error
I need to create trigger BEFORE UPDATE test what change and put that change to table logi

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `logs`;

DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`ams`@`%` TRIGGER `logs` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `faktury` FOR EACH ROW 
begin 
IF (new.uwagi != old.uwagi) THEN
BEGIN
INSERT logs (`text_logi`, `lp`, `tabela_logi`) VALUES ( CONCAT(CONCAT("Zmiana magazynu: ",old.uwagi," -> ", new.uwagi), new.lp_fvat, "FAKTURY" );
END; 
end if;
if (new.klient != old.klient) THEN
BEGIN                                                           
INSERT logs (`text_logi`, `lp`, `tabela_logi`) VALUES ( CONCAT(CONCAT("Zmiana magazynu: ",old.klient," -> ", new.klient), new.lp_fvat, "FAKTURY" );
END;
end if;
INSERT logs (`text_logi`, `lp`, `tabela_logi`) VALUES ( CONCAT(CONCAT("Zmiana magazynu: ",old.magazyn," -> ", new.magazyn), new.lp_fvat, "FAKTURY" );
END;
end if;
if (new.data_faktury != old.data_faktury) THEN
BEGIN             
INSERT logs (`text_logi`, `lp`, `tabela_logi`) VALUES ( CONCAT(CONCAT("Zmiana magazynu: ",old.data_faktury," -> ", new.data_faktury), new.lp_fvat, "FAKTURY" );
END;                                                           
end if;     
end //
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';
END;
end if;
if (new.klient != old.klient) THEN
BEGIN                 ...' at line 6
```

Could you please any one give me tha idea to solve this?

Comment: You don't need all those begin..ends just a begin at the start and an end at the end will do.

Comment: No closing parenthesis in first INSERT. And there are more syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `logs`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`ams`@`%` TRIGGER `logs` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `faktury` FOR EACH ROW 
begin 
IF (new.uwagi != old.uwagi) THEN
BEGIN
IF (new.uwagi != old.uwagi) THEN
BEGIN
INSERT logs (`text_logi`, `lp`, `tabela_logi`) VALUES ( CONCAT(CONCAT("Zmiana magazynu: ",old.uwagi," -> ", new.uwagi), new.lp_fvat, "FAKTURY" ));
END; 
end if;
if (new.klient != old.klient) THEN
BEGIN                                                           
INSERT logs (`text_logi`, `lp`, `tabela_logi`) VALUES ( CONCAT(CONCAT("Zmiana magazynu: ",old.klient," -> ", new.klient), new.lp_fvat, "FAKTURY" ));
END;
end if;
INSERT logs (`text_logi`, `lp`, `tabela_logi`) VALUES ( CONCAT(CONCAT("Zmiana magazynu: ",old.magazyn," -> ", new.magazyn), new.lp_fvat, "FAKTURY" ));
END;
end if;
if (new.data_faktury != old.data_faktury) THEN
BEGIN             
INSERT logs (`text_logi`, `lp`, `tabela_logi`) VALUES ( CONCAT(CONCAT("Zmiana magazynu: ",old.data_faktury," -> ", new.data_faktury), new.lp_fvat, "FAKTURY" ));
END;                                                           
end if; 
end//
```

Comment: The third insert seems to be (As in the question) missing an if and a begin. And the first if is repeated (a typo?)

Comment: that was only missing closing parenthesis in each insert

Comment: Yes that was parenthesis

Comment: please explain your answer with query .